# How to email the output of Excel exporter plugin

Tags: excel, email, grails, export

We are using this plugin to generate Excel reports: https://github.com/TouK/excel-export and this plugin to mail them out: https://grails.org/plugin/mail .

The problem is how to get the output of the Excel-export into the mail as an attachment without having to save it to disk as a file (as we have thousands of them and don't know if we can write to FS etc).

We are guessing along these lines:

```
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    def withProperties = ['name', 'description']
    List<String> products = ['john', 'lazy']
    new XlsxExporter().add(products, withProperties).save(outputStream)

    sendMail {
        mutipart true
        async true
        to "hello@me.com"
        subject reportSchedule.report.name
        from "reports@me.com"
        body 'Report: '  + reportSchedule.report.name + " took: 20s"
        attach "yourfile.txt", "text/plain", inputStream
    }
```

The question is, how do we hookup the output stream from the Excel exporter to the input stream required by the mail plugin?

Also tried this:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray())

    sendMail {
        multipart true
        async true
        to "hello@me.com"
        subject reportSchedule.report.name
        from "hello@me.com"
        body 'Report: '  + reportSchedule.report.name + " took: 20s"
        attach "yourfile.txt", "text/plain", inputStream
    }
```

but this gives:

```
attach() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.ByteArrayInputStream)
```

and this:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    def withProperties = ['name', 'description']
    List<String> products = ['john', 'lazy']
    new XlsxExporter().add(products, withProperties).save(outputStream)

    sendMail {
        multipart true
        async true
        to "me@me.com"
        subject reportSchedule.report.name
        from "me@me.com"
        body 'Report: '  + reportSchedule.report.name + " took: 20s"
        attach "report.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", outputStream.toByteArray()
    }
```

This does attach an .xlsx file to the email of about 3k in size, but it is blank, completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

OK problem solved.  The correct way is:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

def withProperties = ['name', 'description']
List<Product> products = ProductFactory.getSome()
new XlsxExporter().add(products, withProperties).save(outputStream)

sendMail {
    multipart true
    async true
    to "me@me.com"
    subject reportSchedule.report.name
    from "me@me.com"
    body 'Report: '  + reportSchedule.report.name + " took: 20s"
    attach "report.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", outputStream.toByteArray()
}
```

Where I was going wrong was simply the products need to be be complex objects with fields which match the headers, not just strings.